# estimates based on gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution

i am a scientific management student. i am studying about the estimate about surgery time. this is a paper by Norman T. J. Bailey. the paper is<< A Study of Queues and Appointment Systems in Hospital Out-Patient Departments, with Special Reference to Waiting-Times >> which illustrate the Bailey rule

but due to my lack of math knowledge , I cannot understand this part. Could you please help me with it > or could you please give me some advice?[image]

Comment: Please be more specific, because you haven't asked an answerable question: you have only expressed a state of mind.  Exactly what don't you understand about this page?

Comment: Baily just explains here that if you assume the surgery times have a Gamma distribution, you can estimate the two parameters $p$ and $\gamma$ of that distribution from a set of measured surgery times $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ using Maximum Likelihood. I believe Baily's rule is to schedule two patients right away at the start of the session, and then space them apart according to their expected surgery time. He validated that rule in another paper using simulation in the 1950s. But as whuber says, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst   Thanks for your answer. I think I was a little confused about the writer's intend for writing those derivation at that time . But after I read it again and again I think I have improved my understanding. Can you explain the sentence in your answer" Baily's rule is to schedule two patients right away at the start of the session, and then space them apart according to their expected surgery time". I cannot understand it totally. But I am sure it is very important for me. please!

Comment: @rene smith: see Bailey N.T.J. "A note on equalising the mean waiting times of successive customers in a finite queue", Journal of the Statistical Society, Series B, Vol. 17, No. 2, 1955, pp. 262-263. You can easily find it on JSTOR and it explicitly refers to the paper from which you got the screenshot in your question. I should also note that in the last few years, many many papers have appeared that attempt to study appointment scheduling under various assumptions and circumstances.